# Not Able to Connect with MAC System in Xamarin.IOS using VisualStudio 2017

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, microsoft-metro

**The Installesd  Xamarin.IOS (version  10.8)  on the MAC  Xamarin Team  is not  compatible with  the local  Xamarin.IOS  (version 10.2) . PLease select  a new server  or install the correct  Xamarin.IOS versions.**

I am getting the above issue while connecting with the MAC from Visual Studio 2017.I did Unistall and Installed VS two times. for this , we have wasted threee days of time.

please anyone provide the solution for the above issue.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: The solution is kind of obvious I think. Make sure the Xamarin versions on your Mac and your local machine match.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Xamarin.ios updates both on PC and Mac. Download and install all the updates, make the version of your Xamarin.ios up to date.

To check the Xamarin.ios updates on PC:

1. Open Visual Studio.
2. Tools->Options...->Xamarin->Other.
3. Select **Stable** and click the Check Now button.

[image]

On Mac:

1. Open Visual Studio for Mac.
2. Click the **Visual Studio ...** tab right after the Apple icon on the top-left of screen.
3. Click **Check for Updates...**
4. If it is not on stable channel, choose **Stable** and click on **Switch
   channel** button.

[image]

You can check the versions both on PC and Mac for xamarin.ios in VS.

Check the xamarin.ios version on PC:

- Help->About Microsoft Visual Studio.

On Mac:

- Visual Studio ...->About Visual Studio ...->Show Details.

At this time (9/4/2017), the latest stable version of Xamarin.ios is `10.12`. When you update both them, try to connect them again.

References:

- [Change the Updates
  Channel](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/)
- [How can I update the Xamarin.IOS version on my
  MAC?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79306/how-can-i-update-the-xamarin-ios-version-on-my-mac)

Comment: Hi @Divya Vani, did my answer help you ?